# I want to stop/Pause the designer workflows which are associated with sharepoint list and restart once the new version updated?

Tags: powershell, workflow, restart, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

We have a sharepoint list and few designer workflows are associated with it. We have made some changes to the existing workflow but not published as it might affect the current list items where we have reassigned permission and status for many list items. In this case we would like to stop workflows which are still running or in progress for specific list items in Sharepoint list. once the deployemnt is done (New version of the workflow is published), we need to restart the workflows for the list items we stopped.

I believe this is possible through Powershell script.

please post our suggestions and solution if you have an idea.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

```html
#Site URL
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://urlforsite.com";
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true;    

#List Name
$list = $web.Lists["ListName"];

# Iterate through all Items in List and all Workflows on Items.         
foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
foreach ($wf in $item.Workflows) {

#Cancel Workflows        
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager]::CancelWorkflow($wf);      
}
}
$web.Dispose();
```

To restart any workflow, you can just had a column to a personal view as either a yes/no choice.  On the existing workflow do an if statement for the column to change then change back.